# truthtable for nested equation

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a prolog program to print out the truthtable of a statement. It works fine for the example `truthtable(A,B,and(A,B))`,
but if I try `truthable(A,B,or(A,and(A,B)))` it doesn't work and shows everything as `false`.

```
and(true,true):- true.
and(false,true):-false.
and(true,false):-false.
and(false,false):-false.
or(true,true):-true.
or(false,true):-true.
or(true,false):-true.
or(false,false):-false.
non(true):-false.
non(false):-true.

evaluate(E, true) :- E, !.
evaluate(E, false).

bool(true).
bool(false).

truthtable(A,B,E):-
    bool(A), 
    bool(B), 
    write(A), 
    write('  \t  '), 
    write(B), 
    write('  \t  '), 
    evaluate(E, R), 
    write(R), 
    nl, 
    fail.
```

Also what can I do if I want the user to add any number of inputs for example A,B and C not only A and B.

Comment: to debug prolog programs you could use trace predicate, i.e. `trace,truthtable(A,B,or(A,and(A,B))),notrace.` If you do, you will see where it doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: Also check how would your program respond to `or(true,or(true,true))`

Comment: shows false .. @DmitriChubarov

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154122/truthtable-based-on-equation)? You might want to just update that one.

Comment: For something similar see: [Rosetta Code - Arithmetic evaluation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic_evaluation#Prolog).

Comment: The example of `or(true,or(true,true))` shows that your definitions of `evaluate/2`,`or/2`, `and/2`, and `non/1` do not handle nesting correctly. You could fix it if you augment your definition by defining `or(A,B)` where either `\+ bool(A)` or `\+ bool(B)`, or both, and similarly extend the definitions of `and/2` and `non/1` with additional clauses.

Comment: Of interest: [Truth table maker](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_13.html)

Comment: Of interest: [Truth Table](http://barrywatson.se/cl/cl_truth_table.html)

Comment: In Prolog, `false` means just that. It's logical failure. So for example, if you evaluate `and(true, false)` in your code, it will just fail because you've define it to fail with `false`. If you want to take this approach, try using facts like, `and(true, false, false).` to indicate that the result of `and` of `true` and `false` is `false`.